# make: just build dependencies of a target, not the target itself

Tags: makefile

Suppose I have this Makefile

```
A: A_src
   recipe1

B: B_src
   recipe2

F: A B F_src
   recipe3
```

I want a command like `make dependencies F` that will only execute `recipe1` and `recipe2`, NOT `recipe3`. The usecase is the following: I want to interactively edit the file  `F_src` and the editor requires the objects B and A  (not just their sources) to be fully functional. However, before starting to edit `F_src`, I don't waste time building F, which `make F` would do additionally.

Answer (score 0):

You need another target:

```
edit_F: A B
```

which is empty (ie no rules of its own) just has dependencies

Comment: Yes, that would work. But I was hoping to not have to change my Makefile, which is autogenerated anyway.